# Based on Gatling report, how to make sure 100 requests are processed in less than 1 second

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

how can I check my requirement of 100 requests are processed in less than 1 second in my gatling3 report. I ran this using jenkins.

my simulation looks like as below

```
rampConcurrentUsers(1) to (100) during (161 second),
constantConcurrentUsers(100) during (1 minute)
```

Below is my response time percentile graph of two executions for an interval of one second.

[enter image [[image: description]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJLqs.png) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2DN7.png)

[image]

What does the min,max here will tell us, i am assuming the percentages 25%-99% are the completion of the request.

Answer (score -1):

Those graph sections are not what you're after - they show the distribution of response times and the number of active users.

- So min is the fastest response time
- max is the longest
- 95% is the response time for which 95% of your requests were under
- and so on...

So what you could do is look at the section of your graph corresponding to the 100 constant concurrent users injection stage. In this part you would require that the max response time always be under 1 second

(Note: there's something odd with your 2nd report - I assume it didn't come from running the stated injection profile as it has more than 100 concurrent users active)